# Congruence problem $BF = FC$

Tags: geometry, triangles

We have an $ABC$ triangle in which $\angle ABD=\angle ACB,AB=12,AD=8,BC=15,DF\perp BC$.How to show that $[BF]\equiv[FC]$

I did a figure in geogebra but i don't see what triangles are similar i know that one angle is equal if I knew $BD=?$ I could show that $ABD$ and $ACD$ triangles are similar from side-angle-side

[image]

Comment: It might be hard to answer your question as it now stands. Try editing it to finish the unfinished sentences and clarify your thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hints towards a solution. If you're stuck, show what you've tried.

1. Show that $ABD, ACB$ are similar triangles.
2. Hence calculate $DC$.
3. Hence show $BD$ is an angle bisector.
4. Hence $BDC$ is an isosceles triangle, and $BF = FC$.

Comment: How can i show that $ABD$ and $ACB$ are similar triangles?

Comment: What have you tried? What is your first instinct to showing that 2 triangles are similar?

Comment: well there are two options i either prove it from AA but i only have one angle and i dont know how to prove that another angle is equal or from SAS but then I dont have AC and BD to show that $\frac{AB}{AC}=\frac{BD}{BC}$

Comment: AAA is a good approach, esp since we don't know much about the other side lengths as yet. For clarity, which angle do you know is identical? Can you hazard a guess for which other angle we can quickly show is identical?

Comment: Oh wow i think im blind or just very tired,$\angle BAD = \angle BAC $

Comment: Glad you caught it now :)